# Illustrator- Resize different proportioned objects proportionally with fixed dimensions

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm working with two rectangles, one is 50x50px and the other is 46.3x46.3px. Oddly specific, no? But it's to illustrate my issue.

I'm trying to figure out if I can resize one object and simultaneously resize the other proportionally, but with fixed dimensions. See, when I select both objects and I want the smaller one to be 60x60px, then how big will the bigger object become exactly? If I select both objects and they are perfectly aligned, the bounding box and transformation tools will only tell me the height of the bigger box.

Using the transform each command is out of question, because it does not let me specify the dimensions for a key object.

Who can tell me how to achieve it, without using a calculator and math, if it can be done at all?

Answer (score 2):

Here two squares

The red = 50 px x 50 px

The green = 43 px x 43 px

Create an horizontal guide at the squares's base.

Select the guide > Menu **Object** > **Transform** > **Move** > Horizontal = 0 / Vertical -60px > **Copy**

Select the squares and resize them proportionally, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>, until the smaller square touch the top guide.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know you stated "no math" but you could merely increase the size of the larger rectangle by the same pixel difference.

60 - 46.3 = 13.7

Larger rectangle should be 63.7x63.7px to be the same proportional enlargement.

Math isn't *always* bad `:)` Especially when it takes only a couple seconds to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a script to allow you to automatically scale elements](https://gist.github.com/ruandre/7b47cbf2a4c55dac9adb).

All you have to do is have an artboard that is the final dimensions that you want. In my example I also used a stroke to show you that it will subtract the stroke from the final dimensions.

So `60px - 1pt stroke = 59px` just keep this in mind.

[image]